# Keyboard hides EditText inside a ScrollView in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, scrollview, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I have nested LinearLayouts which one of them has group of vertical EditText inside a ScrollView. The problem Every time I click one of those EditText and the Keyboard in android arises half of those EditText disappear and if I write in the first Edit Text, I cannot even see it or scroll into it.

I have tried different solution mention here in Stackoverflow like adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"` but to no avail.

Here is my **MainActivity.xml**

```
 LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/clac"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Letter Grade"
            android:textSize="15sp"

            />
        <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Credit Hours"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/inputform">

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_gravity="center"

        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:orientation="vertical">


            <EditText
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/crs1" />
            <EditText
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/crs2" />
            <EditText
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/crs3" />
            <EditText
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/crs4" />
            <EditText
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/crs5" />
            <EditText
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/crs6" />
            <EditText
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/crs7" />

        </LinearLayout>





        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <EditText
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/credit1" />
            <EditText
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/credit2" />
            <EditText
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/credit3" />
            <EditText
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/credit4" />
            <EditText
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/credit5" />
            <EditText
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/credit6" />
            <EditText
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/credit7" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Current GPA"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>
    <EditText

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/currentgpa"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Taken Hours"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>
    <EditText

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/currenthours"/>

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Reset"
        android:onClick="clearForm"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Calculate"
        android:onClick="Calculate"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="GPA"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/gpa"/>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you I appreciate any help.

Comment: Adding android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan to the mainfest solves the problem of EditText hiding however the scrollView doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 5):

According to your problem use following in your activity manifest

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> </activity>
```

### adjustPan

The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft keyboard.
For more information about this please visit

> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I've tried that and the problem of disappearing EditText is solved however another problem arises which is the ScrollView doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Actually its your xml problem,thats why scrolling not appear

Comment: So how to fix this xml problem? you can see that the scrollview is wrapped inside LinearLayout however the problem persists?!

Answer (score 1):

you have only declare **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"** in your manifeast file remove **adjustResize** from manifeast.

Answer (score 0):

I build your code on my device and adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`in Manifest file helps

IN your xml file

something something

```
   <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/inputform"
        >

        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"

            >
```

something something

I just searched in google "scrollview cut edittext" and answer comes up. You are a programmer, you must make things done by yourself ;)

Comment: Yeah but as you can see the ScorllView doesn't work anymore.

Comment: It's your xml file fault

Comment: Thank you, but How to fix it ?!

Comment: check my answer again.

Comment: i guess you want also make edittext only singleline so there is a parametr in xml going by the same name.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because your buttons layout is included in the scrollview, so when the keyboard appears the buttons layout will occupy some space. You can change your layout like this:(set the `windowSoftInputMode` as `adjustPan`)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_below="@id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Letter Grade"
            android:textSize="15sp"

            />

        <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:text="Credit Hours"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="clearForm"
            android:text="Reset" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="Calculate"
            android:text="Calculate" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gpa"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:text="GPA" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:layout_above="@id/buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/inputform"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"

                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/crs1"
                        android:layout_width="48dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:gravity="center" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/crs2"
                        android:layout_width="48dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/crs3"
                        android:layout_width="48dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/crs4"
                        android:layout_width="48dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/crs5"
                        android:layout_width="48dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/crs6"
                        android:layout_width="48dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/crs7"
                        android:layout_width="48dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center" />

                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/credit1"
                        android:layout_width="48dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:gravity="center" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/credit2"
                        android:layout_width="48dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/credit3"
                        android:layout_width="48dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/credit4"
                        android:layout_width="48dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/credit5"
                        android:layout_width="48dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/credit6"
                        android:layout_width="48dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/credit7"
                        android:layout_width="48dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:text="Current GPA" />

                <EditText

                    android:id="@+id/currentgpa"
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:text="Taken Hours" />

                <EditText

                    android:id="@+id/currenthours"
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />

            </LinearLayout>



        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```